# Issue with Multiple select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using multiple select statements and cases in my query for get the result. Please have a look on my query which I am trying to sort it out. But it is giving me an error with the aggregate function. what I am trying to do is, I have 3 budget criteria and result should be according to that. They are:

```
Budget 2015
Budget Jan-july2015
Budget July-dec2015
```

in the first field I am getting budget for whole 2015 year, in second I want budget expenses from `july-dec2015` as 'current budget' and in third both budget for `jan-july2015` and `july-dec2015` should be added as 'cumulative expenses'.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies'
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Consultants%' THEN 'Consultants'
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Patient%' THEN 'Patient Care'
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Equipment%' THEN 'Equipments' 
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Expense%' THEN 'Other Expenses' 
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Alteration%' THEN 'Alterations/Renovations' ELSE 'Alterations/Renovations' END,
    SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS buget , (Select sum(T0.[CrdRLTotal]/85) where T2.[Name] = 'July-Dec2015' ) as 'CurrentBudget',
    (select sum(T0.[CrdRLTotal]/85) + 'CurrentBudget' where T2.[Name] = 'jan-july2015') as 'Cummulative' 
FROM OBGT 
T0 INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode] INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId] where T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY CASE WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
              WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
              WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies'
              WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Consultants%' THEN 'Consultants' 
              WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Patient%' THEN 'Patient Care' 
              WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Equipment%' THEN 'Equipments'
              WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Expense%' THEN 'Other Expenses'
              WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Alteration%' THEN 'Alterations/Renovations' ELSE 'Alterations/Renovations' END
```

I am not getting idea how to get all fields which are required.

Comment: Use a derived table or cte to simplify code. (I.e. to avoid writing that huge CASE twice.)

Comment: you say you get an error, what error is that?

Comment: @jarlh  can you help me out to get required result from this query or you have another query to get required result

Comment: @TZHX Column 'OBGS.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You have clear error message - can you alter your query to 'include OBGS.Name either into aggregate function or GROUP BY clause'?

Comment: i know this thing. but i dont know how to sort it out. thats why i put here. @Arvo

Comment: According to error message, start your GROUP BY this way: `GROUP BY T2.Name, CASE...`. You may need to include more columns into GROUP BY clause.

Comment: but those coulmns includes another select statement @Arvo . if i do like this this is giving me another syntax error .

Comment: i am just struggling with this thing from so long. please help me out if you can. @Arvo

Comment: Actually your syntax is a bit messy, looking closer I do not like fields like next: `Select sum(T0.[CrdRLTotal]/85) where T2.[Name] = 'July-Dec2015'`. What value you need? Either you have to sum over current tables (then no `select` is needed) or you should write proper select statement (like `select sum(X...) from table X where X... = ...`).

Comment: @Arvo i need [CrdRLTotal]/85) value from T0 table where Budget(T2.[Name]) should be July-Dec2015. i have written in query. but dont know how to write in proper way. so that i could get the result..

Answer (score 1):

This is **NOT** an answer, just to show how the code can be written in shorter form using a derived table for t1.

```
SELECT T1.[AcctName],
       SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS buget,
       (Select sum(T0.[CrdRLTotal]/85) where T2.[Name] = 'July-Dec2015' ) as 'CurrentBudget',
       (select sum(T0.[CrdRLTotal]/85) + 'CurrentBudget' where T2.[Name] = 'jan-july2015') as 'Cummulative' 
FROM OBGT T0
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Consultants%' THEN 'Consultants'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Patient%' THEN 'Patient Care'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Equipment%' THEN 'Equipments' 
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Expense%' THEN 'Other Expenses' 
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Alteration%' THEN 'Alterations/Renovations'
                ELSE 'Alterations/Renovations'
           END as [AcctName],
           [AcctCode]
    from OACT
    ) as T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
where T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY T1.[AcctName]
```

Comment: I tried with this code before. it is giving me The multi-part identifier "T1.AcctName" could not be bound. error..

Comment: if you know answer then please tell me.